How can I make the tx.origin not equal to the msg.sender? Ethers Signers
I'm trying to complete this challenge:
alchemy challenge
My script to deploy the contract and to call attempt function with different addr:
My script
const hre = require("hardhat");
require("dotenv").config();

async function main() {
  const Contract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Contract");
  const contract = await Contract.deploy();

  console.log(`Contract was deployed to ${contract.target}`);

  const [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();

  await contract.connect(addr1).attempt();
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

I get this error:

ProviderError: execution reverted: msg.sender is equal to tx.origin

Any help please?

Create an smart contract and call it from an EOA.
EOA -> Smart Contract -> Your challenge
tx.origin will be EOA (as it's where the tx started) and msg.sender will be Smart Contract (as it's the one that calls the challenge)
You can read more about it in this post
